# javascript hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, multiple-inheritance, hasownproperty

I'm trying to get some of my types to have a kind of multiple 'inheritance' like so:

```
UIControls.ClickableMesh.prototype = Object.create(THREE.Mesh.prototype);

var UIConProto = Object.create(UIControls.UIControl.prototype);

for(var i in UIConProto){
    if(UIConProto.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        UIControls.ClickableMesh.prototype[i] = UIConProto[i];
    }
}
```

But the for loop isn't adding any of `UIControls.UIControl.prototype` properties to my new types prototype `UIControls.ClickableMesh.prototype`. Why is `hasOwnProperty` returning false for eveything? there should be some members of it which are directly of the object.

Comment: Because `UIConProto` is an empty object, it does not have any direct properties, it *inherits* everything from `UIControls.UIControl.prototype`. Do `console.dir(UIConProto);` and you will see. The [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) clearly states: *"This method can be used to determine whether an object has the specified property as a direct property of that object; unlike the `in` operator, **this method does not check down the object's prototype chain**"*.

Comment: Why do you think there should be any properties directly on the object? This doesn't work either (like its supposed to) -- http://jsfiddle.net/WrqwE/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty` only returns true when the property belongs to the object itself, instead of inheriting from its prototype. For instance:

```
function Foo() {
  this.n = 123;
}
Foo.prototype.s = "hello";

var foo = new Foo();

foo.hasOwnProperty("s"); // False, since s is inherited from the prototype object.
foo.hasOwnProperty("n"); // True, since n is the property of foo itself.
```

You may notice the way `Object.create()` create your object, which falls into the first category of the sample above.

Comment: hi, thanks, I knew how hasOwnProperty worked, I thought that Object.create made a copy of the argument, I wasn't aware that it made a new blank object with the argument as it's first prototype, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> hasOwnProperty  ... unlike the *in* operator, this method **does not
>   check down the object's prototype chain**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Objects in JS are hash-maps and the sole purpose of the hasOwnProperty  is to check if that hash-map contains that property. hasOwnProperty does not traverse `__proto__` chain.